# Prefix www to url causes redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, redirect-loop

I am writing this question because I am unable to comment in a question as I dont have atleast 50 points.
Well, I have tried almost every possible methods answered here regarding adding a 'www' prefix to my site. But I end up with having a redirect loop error. You can check my website : www.pharmazonelab.com . When I remove the .htaccess file and enter [www.pharmazonelab.com](http://www.pharmazonelab.com) in the address bar, it automatically redirect to non-www pharmazonelab.com . I am unable to figure out the problem and cant find a fix to it.

My .htaccess file contains this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any expert can help out. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you show your existing `.htaccess`?

Comment: @Rakesh if your hosting is using cPanel, you will have log into it select your domain and change the redirect that is there from www to non-www or vice-verse depending on what you want, otherwise it will go into a loop and fail.

Comment: @Prix You saved my day... Thanks your answer worked. I never knew about it that it can be changed from cpanel. Now its working. Thank you. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your domain using `curl` and it is indeed showing a redirection loop but **important fact I found was that it is using Nginx instead of Apache**. Hence redirect rule shown in your question won't work.

On `NgInx` you can use this snippet to redirect to `www`:

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name _;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://www.bedom.com;
}
```

Make sure this `server` block is **very last one** after other `server` blocks.

Comment: I didnt have to try it. Prix's answer solved it. But thanks for your suggestion. It may help me in future.